# Does an astrologer get karma by reading someone's horoscope and suggesting remedies?

Tags: karma, astrology, horoscopes

I have heard this from an astrologer that they get negative karma by reading horoscopes and suggesting remedies because they help in delaying the results of bad karma for a person.

Have you heard of anything similar? It would be good to have some scriptural evidence in this regard or even a reference from any renowned astrologer's work would help.

Comment: He who takes unlawful gifts goes to the Adhomukha (or head-inverted) hell; as does one who offers sacrifices to improper objects, and an observer of the stars (for the prediction of events). https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm

Answer (score 3):

Astrology is used to predict future events and find solutions or prevents from any negative event to be occurred. 
Considering your question , if a doctor operates a patient who is suffering from a disease and prevents it from teatment and saves a patient life does he get a bad karma ? It's just his mere duty (karma) to save patient and so it's an astrologer duty to rescue his patient from bad occuring.
In the world of karma there is nothing like positive and negative , good and bad anything like that . 
In not an astrologer nor ever met one but just it's my opinion from karmic view point.

Comment: Well by this logic i also thought it should not, but then coming from an experienced astrologer i couldn't deny the fact either. Also the citation in the comment to vishu-puran states that the person can even go to hell - http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm